# NO Response from Instagram Real Time Update

Tags: java, javascript

Im working on the Real Time Updates in the instagram API.

When I hit the instagram with the call back url and hash tag. It returned me

```
{
meta: {
code: 200
}-
data: [0]
}
```

Here is my code for the tag Subscription,

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

String requestUrl= "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions";
String subscriptionUrl="client_secret=xxx&client_id=xx&object=tag&aspect=media&object_id=tagName&verify_token=xx&callback_url=http://mycallbackUrl.htm";

connection      =   (HttpURLConnection) new URL(requestUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(subscriptionUrl.getBytes().length));
                connection.connect();

DataOutputStream wr     =   new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(subscriptionUrl);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

InputStream stream  = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(stream);
BufferedReader bufferStream = new BufferedReader(reader);
String readResponse;
StringBuffer response   = new StringBuffer();

while((readResponse = bufferStream.readLine()) !=null)
{
response.append(readResponse);
}
bufferStream.close();
```

THIS IS MY GET REQUEST WITH HUB CHANLLENGE,

```
String fetchContent;
String responsetUrl=    "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=8a3c35a329ad44fa82c0f006fc48a2d7&client_id=f90b48725f844e61bb2672d83011fcd8&hub.challenge="+hubchallenge;
HttpURLConnection connections=  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(responsetUrl).openConnection();
connections.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader br= new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connections.getInputStream()));

while((fetchContent = br.readLine()) !=null)
log.info("the hubchallenge response::"+fetchContent);
```

With this I got the hub Challenge, but the response data is empty .With the hub chanllenge I made the GET request to the instagram . 
And when I upload a picture with the subscribed hash tag,there no response from the instagram.

Can anyone tell what Im missing.

Answer (score 0):

http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

I haven't fully understood your code, but i think you follow the wrong steps.

When you make the POST request to "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/", the Instagram server doesn't answer right away. Instead he makes a GET request to your callback url. Your code should receive this GET request, read the querystring parameter "hub.challenge", and return it as a simple String. The Instagram server will get your response, see that the hub.challenge is the same as the one he sent, and create your subscription. Then he will respond to your initial POST request which was waiting all this time.

I also implemented this on Java, and i used two servlets.

This servlet method reads a tag from a textbox and tries to subscribe:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException
    {
        String tag = request.getParameter("tag");
        String url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions";
        try
        {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            String urlParameters = "client_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(Constants.clientId, "UTF-8") + "&client_secret="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(Constants.clientSecret, "UTF-8") + "&object=tag&aspect=media&object_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(tag, "UTF-8")
                    + "&verify_token=" + URLEncoder.encode("my_password", "UTF-8") + "&callback_url=" + URLEncoder.encode(Constants.callbackUrl, "UTF-8");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            System.out.println(json);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        try
        {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

On another servlet this code gets the GET request from the Instagram server and returns the hub.challenge String:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String mode = request.getParameter("hub.mode");
        String challenge = request.getParameter("hub.challenge");
        String verifyToken = request.getParameter("hub.verify_token");
        // you should check that these values are ok
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(challenge);
        writer.flush();
    }
```

After subscribing successfully, i use this code to listen to the subscription events:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        BufferedReader body = request.getReader();
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = body.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result.append(inputLine);
        }
        body.close();
        String str = result.toString();
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(str);
            if (jsArray != null && jsArray.length() > 0)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < jsArray.length(); index++)
                {
                    JSONObject json = jsArray.optJSONObject(index);
                    System.out.println(json);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code has to be on the same servlet as before, the one that is described by your callback url.